# Android Jtest - How to invoke a MenuItem from the dropdown list programmatically

Tags: android, junit

This is the dropdown list which is `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` in xml

[image: MenuItem I wish to test]

My question is how to trigger the `.setOnMenuItemClickListener()` listener, and perform my test for it.

I've tried to:

1. Consider it as button, and do `.performClick();`
2. Consider it as radio button, and do `.toggle();`
3. Use `TouchUtils.clickView(this, button);`

And none of them work. How can I test this?